# Cannot view PNG image of docusign document

Tags: docusignapi

I trying to use the Docusign REST api to retrieve a page image from a specified envelope.

Using the GetDocumentPageImage api call specified in the docusign's developer resources:
https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/getDocumentPageImage/

When I make a call, I receive in the response header:

```
content-type:image/png
```

When I save the raw binary to disk and try to open it, it doesn't seem to be a PNG file. Opening the file a text editor to inspect the contents shows that th file begins with:

```
˝PNG IHDR...
```

which seems to be a valid PNG file header, but ends with:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" >
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <title>Image</title>
        <meta name="GENERATOR" Content="Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 7.1">
        <meta name="CODE_LANGUAGE" Content="C#">
        <meta name="vs_defaultClientScript" content="JavaScript">
        <meta name="vs_targetSchema" content="http://schemas.microsoft.com/intellisense/ie5">
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex, noarchive" />
    </HEAD>
    <body MS_POSITIONING="GridLayout">
        <form method="post" action="./image.aspx" id="Form1">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUKLTUxMTcwNzgxMGRkQRcFn//jRJ+06xbvFxUi4rKEZIQb6fRuQKDtT8P6CNnm/JfLfRFk+peLPbzp4xXAtupqCca4iRWWnIYdQRieIA==" />

<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="40952B3F" />
        </form>
    </body>
</HTML>
```

I tried to strip the end part of the file that has the Microsoft rubbish with no luck. It seems the response content has been encoded differently some way and the docs don't explain what this is and how to decode.

Comment: Do you get this with one specific envelope or every you attempt to download a page from?

Comment: Could you post your code? Also try posting the form you got - may be you will get the image (`action="./image.aspx"` looks like an action to display an image). Also check HTTP status of your reply.

Comment: Can you please post your entire response and Headers.  The HTML tags at the end of the file should not cause any issues with open the PNG file. In your request are you specifying the Content-Transfer-Encoding header?